# Tomcat, JDBC Thin Client and Oracle Wallet

Tags: eclipse, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'm having the most difficult time getting JDBC thin client to recognize my Oracle Wallet. This same wallet is used without issue in SQLPlus, SQLDeveloper and even a .NET application. We use it both as a SSO mechanism, i.e., no username and password provided as well as with a username and password for specific purposes.

I have been all over this document: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf

The root exception is:
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: could not resolve the connect identifier "D501_SSL"

I launch Tomcat via Eclipse with these VM arguments:
-Doracle.net.wallet_location="C:\oracle_wallet\SFVRL" -Doracle.net.tns_admin="C:\oracle_wallet\SFVRL"

I have D501_SSL defined in my tnsnames.ora file. Protocol is TCPS on port 2484. It works fine outside of the thin client as previously mentioned.

I have been all over the web and found tickler topics but nothing that works. I've modified my java.security file as directed. I have
the requisite jars in the classpath (ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar, oraclepki.jar, osdt_cert.jar, osdt_core.jar).

I've tried various format on the above options but no joy. I put my tnsnames.ora in the same folder at the wallet to simply things a bit.

I'm running Tomcat 8, JAVA 1.8. Below is my JNDI config. Any insight would be most appreciated.

```
<Resource auth="Container" name="jdbc/SVRSDS_SSL" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" logAbandoned="true" maxActive="24" maxIdle="24" maxWait="-1" minIdle="2" poolPreparedStatements="true" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="30" testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:/@D501_SSL" validationQuery="Select 1 from dual" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "oracle.net.ns.NetException: could not resolve the connect identifier D501_SSL" indicates that the JDBC thin driver couldn't find a TNS name "D501_SSL in your file tnsnames.ora. The error is not related to the wallet configuration so I would first try to resolve this error without trying to configure the wallet. Once the configuration error is resolved you can try to add the wallet.